# Cal-Heatmap: Selecting minimum and maximum days in a month

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar, visualization, momentjs

I'm using [d3](http://d3js.org), [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), and [calheatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/) and I'm trying to select the earliest date in a month on the calendar visualization. Here is how the calendar is setup

```
cal = new CalHeatMap();
    cal.init({
        data: data,
        start: moment("2012-1-1", "YYYY-M-D").utc().toDate(),
        domain: "month",
        subDomain: "day",
        legend: quantScale.quantiles(),
        range: 24,
        cellRadius: 0,
        itemName : metric.value.labels,
        legendVerticalPosition: "top",
        legendMargin: [0, 0, 20, 0],
        legendCellSize: 15
    });
```

I've been trying to use moment.min to select the lowest value in the month, but that doesn't seems to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might go about this?

I'm pretty new in this realm of JavaScript, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would that be the earliest date in your data?

Comment: The earliest date is January 1 and the latest date is August 31. I've been able to get the month and day to log out separately, but I can't get them both to log out at the same time. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're looking for the earliest date in your data, do `new Date(d3.min(d3.keys(data)) * 1000)`.

Comment: Would it be the same for getting the max date out of my data? Also, why times 1000?

Comment: The timestamps are in seconds, the `Date()` constructor takes milliseconds. And yes, you can get the maximum value in the same way.

Comment: Terrific. It worked like a charm. Thank you Lars!